# Values not being insert into Database from JSP form

Tags: html, mysql, sql, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to get the doPost() method in my servlet to insert values from a JSP form into the database, however it doesn't seem to be working and I'd like to know if anyone here could help me out. Thank you. Here's the code below:

```
    public boolean addOrder(Connection conn) {
    boolean success = false;

    // Declare JDBC objects
    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    try {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO OrderInfo(SizeOfPizza, NumOfToppings, Quantity, "
                + " Delivery, Price) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";

        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, order.getPizzaSize());
        ps.setInt(2, order.getNumToppings());
        ps.setInt(3, order.getQuantity());
        ps.setBoolean(4, order.isDelivery());
        ps.setDouble(5, order.getPrice());

        int count = ps.executeUpdate();

        if (count > 0) {
            success = true;
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        DBConnection.closeJDBCObjects(conn, ps);
        return success;
    }
}
```

Servlet to insert into the database

```
    @Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    OrderDAO dao = new OrderDAO();
    DBConnection conn = (DBConnection)this.getServletContext().getAttribute("dbConn");
    boolean ordersuccess = dao.addOrder(conn.getConnection());
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("ordersuccess", ordersuccess);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("ReceiptPage.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Page to fill in form and send off to the servlet

```
    <html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Pizza Order Page</title>
    <%
        String fname = request.getParameter("firstName");
        String lname = request.getParameter("lastName");
    %>
    <style>
        body{
            background-color: silver;
        }
        #title{
            background-color: gray;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="title" align="center">Hello <%out.print(fname + " " + lname);%></h1>

    <p>Please fill out your order information</p>
    <p><b>Delivery Options</b></p>
    <form action="ReceiptServlet.do" method="POST">
        <Select name="deliveryOption">
            <option value="Pick Up">Pick Up</option>
            <option value="Delivery">Delivery</option>          
        </Select>
        <br>
        <p><b>Size Options</b></p>
        <input type="radio" name="size" value="Small">Regular ($5.00)<br><br>
        <input type="radio" name="size" value="Large">Large ($7.00)
        <br>
        <p><b>Topping Choices</b></p>
        <input type="radio" value="Pepperoni" name="topping">Pepperoni ($1.00)</option><br>
        <input type="radio" value="Mushroom" name="topping">Mushroom ($1.00)</option><br>
        <input type="radio" value="Olives" name="topping">Olives ($1.00)</option><br>
        <input type="radio" value="Sausage" name="topping">Sausage ($1.00)</option><br>
        <input type="radio" value="Pineapple" name="topping">Pineapple ($1.00)</option><br>

        <br>
        <p><b>Enter the amount of pizzas you would like to order</b></p>
        <input type="text" name="pizzaQty">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Place Order">
    </form>

</body>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error, or it is just no inserting data into the database

Comment: No errors. Just isn't inserting into the database.

Comment: Just try this. In your addOrder() in the if condition where you check count>0 just add this line Conn.commit() after success=true. And also try to print the count and check what is the value